# Парсинг каждого слова через запятую

Tags: python, строки

Я делаю парсинг excell документа и получаю список элементов. Каждый элемент, это строка в которой через запятую указаны характеристики продукта. Как лучше реализовать отделение их друг от друга?

Допустим, метод возвращает строку "Intel-Core i7 - 10700F, 2.9 GHz, 16MB, oem, LGA1200, Comet Lake". 
Задача из строки сделать коллекцию или json объект в виде

```
{
 "title":"Intel-Core i7 - 10700F",
 "frequency":"2.9 GHz",
 "cache":"16MB",
 "oem":"oem",
 "socket": "LGA1200",
 "gen": "Comet Lake"
 }
```

Comment: ``stroka.split(",")``, а потом уже распределять по ключам в словаре

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = "Intel-Core i7 - 10700F, 2.9 GHz, 16MB, oem, LGA1200, Comet Lake"

res = dict(zip(("title", "frequence", "cache", "oem", "socket", "gen"), s.split(", ")))
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

По приколу ещё такая вариация - названия полей подаются в том же строковом формате, что и значения полей:

```
s = "Intel-Core i7 - 10700F, 2.9 GHz, 16MB, oem, LGA1200, Comet Lake"
d = "title, frequence, cache, oem, socket, gen"
res = dict(zip(*[x.split(', ') for x in (d, s)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд чаще всего самое простое использовать Pandas. Одной командой [читаешь excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel), второй командой сохраняешь в [json, например](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas-dataframe-to-json). Если требуется между ними делаешь дополнительные преобразования данных и аргументами указанных методов настраиваешь чтение и сохранение данных нужным образом.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx') 
df.to_json('example.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

мб стоит попробовать созадать список `s.split(", ")`
а потом список ключей(k) в нужном порядке
а затем

```
 for i in range(k.length()):
        d[k[i]]=s[i]
```